# android - hide horizontal scrollview when textView is clicked

Tags: android, textview, horizontalscrollview

I'm new to android. I'm developing an app. I have a `textView` as the header and a `horizontalscrollview` with the content. When I press the `textView` I got the `horizontalscrollview` appears below.

Java Code for the above method...

```
final HorizontalScrollView hsc = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.dailyUseItemsHS);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daily_use_items_header);

            hsc.setAlpha(0.0f);

            tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                        hsc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        hsc.animate().alpha(1.0f);
                    }
        });
}
```

Now when I press the textview again I need the `horizontalscrollview` to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove             `hsc.setAlpha(0.0f);` and make the `dailyUseItemsHS` invisible in the view xml

In your `onClick` Event :

```
  tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         if(hsc.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
             {
                 hsc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
             else if (hsc.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                 hsc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I forgot to set visibility to GONE... Now the code working 100% perfect.. :) :) :)